# Force zoom setting on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, android

Is there a way to determine the setting of the Force zoom option of a browser?
This option is usually found under Settings, Accessibility, Force Zoom check box.
I need to tell the user to uncheck this if checked. The site will not work properly with it enabled.
I have the viewport set correctly, but this overrides it.

Comment: "This option is usually found under Settings, Accessibility, Force Zoom check box" -- that is a device setting, not a browser setting. I will be very surprised if any Android browsers expose that value to Web content, let alone all Android browsers.

Comment: I have several browsers on my mobile devices. Some have this and some don’t.
Edge, Chrome seem to have this under options. Can be set to the specific browser where Dolphin and Android browser does not have this setting and respond to the viewport setting as expected.
I checked under the device settings and could not find it. It appears to be browser specific.

Comment: I would say that if the website does not work properly with force zoom enabled, then this is a problem of that website, not the browser. The whole point of the force zoom option is to be able to zoom regardless of what the web developer thinks is best for the users. Hint: The reason why people use the force zoom feature is to simply be able to read the text or view other content which they otherwise are unable to see (e.g. due to their poor eyesight).